# R: dplyr duplicated column name

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataset that looks like below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(vector(),ncol=4, nrow = 3))
colnames(df1) <- c("Date","A","B","C")
df1[1,] <- c("2000-01-30","0","1","0")
df1[2,] <- c("2000-01-31","2","0","3")
df1[3,] <- c("2000-02-29","1","2","1")
df1[4,] <- c("2000-03-31","2","1","3")
df1
        Date  A  A  C
1 2000-01-30  0  1  0
2 2000-01-31  2  0  3
3 2000-02-29  1  2  1
4 2000-03-31  2  1  3
```

I'm trying to get:

```
        Date  A  A  C
1    2000-01  2  1  3
2    2000-02  1  2  1
3    2000-03  2  1  3
```

Here is what I did:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df1[,-1] = lapply(df1[,-1], as.numeric)
df1 %>% mutate(Date = as.yearmon(Date)) %>%
group_by(Date) %>%
summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

This works great when there are no duplicate column names. However, given the size of the data, some of the columns may have the same name, which causes the error `found duplicated column name: A`. I do not want to combine the columns, and I want to get the result as mentioned above. Please advise.

Comment: I would go with `names(df1) <- make.unique(names(df1))`

Comment: You can make unique names using the above approach, plus clean up the types inline: `df1 %>% setNames(make.unique(names(.))) %>% mutate_all(type.convert) %>% mutate_at('Date', as.yearmon) %>%
group_by(Date) %>% summarise_all(sum)`